# Add thin lines inbetween rectangles in plotly figure

Tags: plotly, plotly-python

I am currently creating such a plot with **Plotly**, which indicates which Physician works which shift. Since the plot is a bit confusing, I would like to make a modification to the plot.Is it possible to add fine gray lines between the individual rectangles to differentiate the days and the doctors somewhat in color?

[image]

Here is the code for it:

```
def visualize_schedule(days, undercoverage):
 
dic = {(1, 1, 1): 1.0, (1, 1, 2): 0.0, (1, 1, 3): 0.0, (1, 2, 1): 0.0, (1, 2, 2): 1.0, (1, 2, 3): 0.0, (1, 3, 1): 0.0, (1, 3, 2): 0.0, (1, 3, 3): 0.0, (1, 4, 1): 0.0, (1, 4, 2): 1.0, (1, 4, 3): 0.0, (1, 5, 1): 1.0, (1, 5, 2): 0.0, (1, 5, 3): 0.0, (1, 6, 1): 0.0, (1, 6, 2): 1.0, (1, 6, 3): 0.0, (1, 7, 1): 0.0, (1, 7, 2): 1.0, (1, 7, 3): 0.0, (2, 1, 1): 1.0, (2, 1, 2): 0.0, (2, 1, 3): 0.0, (2, 2, 1): 1.0, (2, 2, 2): 0.0, (2, 2, 3): 0.0, (2, 3, 1): 1.0, (2, 3, 2): 0.0, (2, 3, 3): 0.0, (2, 4, 1): 0.0, (2, 4, 2): 0.0, (2, 4, 3): 0.0, (2, 5, 1): 1.0, (2, 5, 2): 0.0, (2, 5, 3): 0.0, (2, 6, 1): 0.0, (2, 6, 2): 0.0, (2, 6, 3): 1.0, (2, 7, 1): 0.0, (2, 7, 2): 1.0, (2, 7, 3): 0.0, (3, 1, 1): 1.0, (3, 1, 2): 0.0, (3, 1, 3): 0.0, (3, 2, 1): 0.0, (3, 2, 2): 1.0, (3, 2, 3): 0.0, (3, 3, 1): 0.0, (3, 3, 2): 0.0, (3, 3, 3): 0.0, (3, 4, 1): 1.0, (3, 4, 2): 0.0, (3, 4, 3): 0.0, (3, 5, 1): 1.0, (3, 5, 2): 0.0, (3, 5, 3): 0.0, (3, 6, 1): 1.0, (3, 6, 2): 0.0, (3, 6, 3): 0.0, (3, 7, 1): 0.0, (3, 7, 2): 1.0, (3, 7, 3): 0.0}

s = pd.Series(dic)

data = (s.loc[lambda s: s == 1]
       .reset_index(-1)['level_2'].unstack(fill_value=0)
       .reindex(index=s.index.get_level_values(0).unique(),
                columns=s.index.get_level_values(1).unique(),
                fill_value=0
                )
       )

data.index = data.index.astype(int)
data.columns = data.columns.astype(str)

title_str = f'Physician Schedules | Total Undercoverage: {undercoverage}'
fig = px.imshow(data[[str(i) for i in range(1, days + 1)]],
                color_continuous_scale=["purple", "orange", "yellow", 'pink'])

fig.update(data=[{'hovertemplate': "Day: %{x}<br>"
                                   "Physician: %{y}<br>"}])

colorbar = dict(thickness=35,
                tickvals=[0, 1, 2, 3],
                ticktext=['Off', 'Evening', 'Noon', 'Morning'])

fig.update(layout_coloraxis_showscale=True, layout_coloraxis_colorbar=colorbar)

x_ticks = np.arange(1, days + 1)
day_labels = ['Day ' + str(i) for i in x_ticks]
fig.update_xaxes(tickvals=x_ticks, ticktext=day_labels)

y_ticks = np.arange(1, data.shape[0] + 1)
physician_labels = ['Physician ' + str(i) for i in y_ticks]
fig.update_yaxes(tickvals=y_ticks, ticktext=physician_labels)

fig.update_layout(
    title={
        'text': title_str,
        'y': 0.98,
        'x': 0.5,
        'xanchor': 'center',
        'yanchor': 'top',
        'font': {'size': 24}
    }
)

fig.update_layout(
    xaxis=dict(
        showgrid=True,
        gridwidth=1.5,
        gridcolor='LightGray'
    ),
    yaxis=dict(
        showgrid=True,
        gridwidth=1.5,
        gridcolor='LightGray'
    )
)

fig.show()
return fig
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the heatmap grid does not seem to be controllable, the idea is to add gaps on the x- and y-axes and set the background color of the graph based on the [reference](https://plotly.com/python/heatmaps/#heatmap-with-categorical-axis-labels) example.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Heatmap(
    z=[[1, 76, 30, 50, 1], [20, 1, 60, 80, 30], [30, 60, 1, -10, 20]],
    x=['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'],
    y=['Morning', 'Afternoon', 'Evening'],
    hoverongaps=False,
    xgap=2,
    ygap=2    
))
fig.update_layout(plot_bgcolor='rgba(211, 211, 211, 1)')
fig.update_xaxes(showgrid=False)
fig.update_yaxes(showgrid=False)
fig.show()
```

[image]